# SQL build column name from results in query

Tags: sql-server, dynamic

I have a table with 60 columns:
`[Actual_Deb01],[Actual_Deb02],[Actual_Deb03],.......,[Actual_Deb60]`

one of the columns in the queries is period and I only want to fetch the actual_debt for the period.

how can I use the period to build the actual_deb col name I want to fetch.
something like:

```
SELECT  Actual_Deb04],
        period,
        ['Actual_Deb'+period]
FROM table
```

`period` in the above is `03` so I want the query to effectively be:

```
SELECT  [Actual_Deb04],
        period,
        [Actual_Deb04]
FROM table
```

Can i do this in the query syntax?

Thanks in advance as always, 
R

Comment: so I want the query to be effectively actual_deb04 or 03?

Answer (score 1):

you can do it with dynamic sql,but what if you have multiple periods ??

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
set @sql=
'select
      [Actual_Deb04],period ,'
      +'Actual_Deb'+period+' FROM table;'

  exec(@sql)
```